# Explanation of a quip in 'A Spy Among Friends'

Tags: a-spy-among-friends

In Episode 2 of 'A Spy Among Friends', Nicholas is told:
"Well, I, for one, think you're obfuscating"

To which he replies:

"Well, now you mention it, I did have plums for breakfast."

Could someone please explain the meaning behind this remark?

Is it perhaps related to the William Carlos Williams poem 'This is Just to Say'?

Comment: I suspect this is reference to the effects of plums which when dried become prunes on the digestive system. It may be a misunderstanding regarding the meaning of obfuscation

Comment: @Paulie_D so you’re saying it’s a poop joke?!

Comment: That's my conclusion

Comment: @Paulie_D Please don't answer in comments. It prevents OP from marking the question as answered, which decreases the value of both question and answer for the rest of the community.

Comment: It's not an answer so it should be a comment. It's just my guess as to the meaning

Comment: This is thin, but: the rhythm and vowels of “obfuscating” somewhat resemble those of “constipated”.